# Code Blocks Process Terminated With Status 127 on linux

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

Recently i installed Code Blocks, done all the linking after that i build and run the program it comes out error with "Process Terminated With Status 127". i tried several ways to solve it like build-essential, g++ but still can't solve it, please help`

-------------- Run: Release Win32 in DeepNeuralNetwork (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/DeepNeuralNetwork/DeepNeuralNetwork/DeepNeuralNetwork
Executing: /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/DeepNeuralNetwork/DeepNeuralNetwork/DeepNeuralNetwork  (in /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/DeepNeuralNetwork/DeepNeuralNetwork/.)
Process terminated with status 127 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

`

Comment: Your next best bet is a debugger.  I suspect you have generated an executable but it encounters an error (The exit code `-1` is often aliased to 255).

Comment: Your messages say "Process terminated with status 127" but the title says 255... which is it

Comment: @BrianCain i tried to comment the exit(-1) but it's still and shows up status 127.

Comment: Yeah, you need a debugger to make progress here.  Attach with `gdb` or Visual Studio before running.  Single-step through `main()` to see where it has trouble.

Comment: disable your antivirus

Comment: now the status become -1, what i'm going to do